# Git push fails with giving validation error

Tags: git

When I try to push my changes to remote it gives below error. Does anyone has an idea?

```
Counting objects: 50, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done. 
Writing objects: 100% (27/27), 1.87 KiB, done. 
Total 27 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)

remote: Validating commit message from [[  ]] for repo [[ ]] 
remote: Validation failed for commit message from [[ ]] for repo [[  ]]
remote: Commit ID [[ Resolving issue related to passenger update notification in check-in flow ]] is wrong To git@10.20.2.20:dcs  
! [remote rejected] dcs_1.9.11 -> dcs_1.9.11 (pre-receive hook declined) 
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@10.20.2.20:dcs'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a [pre-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) on the repo to which you are pushing to, which denies you said push.

You need to contact the admins of that server in order to know more about that specific hook.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a commit message validation hook which JIRA code is mandatary

Comment: in my case the company uses a custom hook which did not provide the reason. It turns out that when the remote branch has been removed, you cannot push changes (after merge or rebase) to that branch which you have locally but no longer exists in `origin`.

Comment: @JuniorMayhé Good catch. I did not see that one before.